# Programing peripherals controllers or slave controller using master using customize bootloader

Tags: stm32, bootloader, master-slave

I am working on a system where I have 2 slave peripherals and a Master controllers. I want to program those 2 slave peripherals using the master controller. Is there any standard protocol or architecture for such programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - but you can use the built in bootloader. In your own protocol send the command to enter the bootloader, then send program it as described in the STM application notes. I do it this way in many of my devices.

How to enter the bootloader? There is many information on internet but some of the advices have a very low quality. You need to switch your micro to the stage as after the reset - then invoke the bootloader. If you use HAL example routime may look like this (STM32F303):

```
void __attribute__((noreturn)) StartBootLoader(void) {
    void (*BootLoad)(void) = (void (*)(void))0x1FFFD804;

    HAL_RCC_DeInit();
    HAL_DeInit();

    SysTick -> CTRL = 0;
    SysTick -> LOAD = 0;
    SysTick -> VAL = 0;

    __set_PRIMASK(1);

    __set_MSP(*(uint32_t *)0x1FFFD800);
    BootLoad();
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: Does this directly jumps to bootloader from the application program..! irrespective of the Boot Pin condition.

Comment: Yes, it invokes the bootloader from the your app. If you need more complex bootloader (for example to encrypt the file) you you need to write one yourself or find/buy something ready.